# How to apply attached behavior right click to text block?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, mvvm-light, attachedbehaviors

I am working on a WPF application and doing my best to follow the MVVM architecture. I am using the GalaSoft MVVM light relay command implementation for all my commands and behavior.

Currently, I am trying to learn and understand attached behaviors, and specifically, how to implement an attached behavior for the text blocks in my application.

What I would like to do is have a style that I can apply to select text blocks that would execute some universal command (more on what I mean by "universal" later)

Here is an example of what I want to do.

For the example, I have two windows. Obviously in the real application I will  have many more, but this should suit my instructive needs.

I'd like to apply an attached behavior to the text blocks in these windows that will implement a defined behavior.... Code...

**Main Window**

```
<Window x:Class="AttachedExample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350"
        Width="525"
        DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=Main}">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Path=SomeMainWindowModel.SomeText}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Main Window View Model**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private MainWindowModel _someMainWindowModel = new MainWindowModel();

    public MainWindowModel SomeMainWindowModel
    {
        get
        {
            return this._someMainWindowModel;
        }
        set
        {
            this._someMainWindowModel = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChange("SomeMainWindowModel");
        }
    }
}
```

**Main Window Model**

```
public class MainWindowModel : BaseModel
{
    private string _someText = "Some main text for Stack Overflow!";

    public string SomeText
    {
        get
        {
            return this._someText;
        }
        set
        {
            this._someText = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChange("SomeText");
        }
    }
}
```

And now the secondary window....

**Secondary Window**

```
<Window x:Class="AttachedExample.SecondaryWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="SecondaryWindow"
        Height="300"
        Width="300"
        DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=Secondary}">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Path=SomeSecondaryWindowModel.SomeSecondaryText}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Secondary Window View Model**

```
public class SecondaryWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private SecondaryWindowModel _someSecondaryWindowModel = new SecondaryWindowModel();

    public SecondaryWindowModel SomeSecondaryWindowModel
    {
        get
        {
            return this._someSecondaryWindowModel;
        }
        set
        {
            this._someSecondaryWindowModel = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChange("SomeSecondaryWindowModel");
        }
    }
}
```

**Secondary Window Model**

```
public class SecondaryWindowModel : BaseModel
{
    private string _someSecondaryText = "Some secondary text for Stack Overflow!";

    public string SomeSecondaryText
    {
        get
        {
            return this._someSecondaryText;
        }
        set
        {
            this._someSecondaryText = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChange("SomeSecondaryText");
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to do is be able to have one style in a resource dictionary or in the App.xaml that I can apply to each of these text blocks. The style would specify an attached behavior that would execute a method with the argument of the content of the text block, right clicked.

**Pseudo Code**

```
*Right Click text block on MainWindow;*

SomeStaticClass.ExecuteSomeStaticCustomMethod(mainWindowTextBlock.Content.ToString());

*Right Click text block on SecondaryWindow;*

SomeStaticClass.ExecuteSomeStaticCustomMethod(secondaryWindowTextBlock.Content.ToString());
```

That's a whole lot of example code and explanation to describe something that could be accomplished with an event handler in the code behind... but that wouldn't be following the MVVM pattern.

Please remember I am using MVVM light in your replies.

Answer (score 0):

THis might be what you are looking for and is MVVM compliant.  I use a style to attach a relay command to the textblock event which is inside a usercontrol, this usercontrol binds to the MVVM_Light Viewmodel and has the datacontext.

```
<Style x:Key="StyleName" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Border x:Name="Bd" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}">
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseRightButtonDown">
                                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.PreviewMouseRightButtonDownCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TextBox}}}"/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I removed the extra style properties to make it easier to read.  You need to create a command in your view model that is called PreviewMouseRightButtonDownCommand of type string.  THen it will get the textblock name as the parameter.  You can change the parameter to whatever binding you want.  THis way whatever textblock I want to trigger this event command just needs to have its style set to this StyleName.

Hope this helps